# How do I force users to enter the wifi password, and prevent it being saved? Using Network Manager

Tags: debian, wifi, networkmanager

I have a classroom of raspberry Pi 3B's (running Raspberry Pi OS - Buster), which students can choose to connect to the wifi network.

I'm using Network Manager, and I'd like to achieve two things:

1. Force users to enter the password for the wifi.
2. Stop users being able to choose to save the password.

It seems to me that selecting 'ask for this password every time' in the 'WiFi Security' tab would be a solution to point (1)... but what I find is that Network Manager never actually prompts users for the password, and simply fails to connect after the "Authentication required by Wi-Fi network" prompt.  I've seen numerous debian users having the same issue, but I've not seen any solutions.

Even if I find a way to fix this, how do I prevent users simply choosing one of the 'store the password...' options?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Setting 'ask for this password every time' is right. That maps to the `wifi-sec.psk-flags` property. See "Secret flag types" in `man nm-settings`.

If NM doesn't have a secret (like by setting always-ask), it will prompt. But for that, there needs to be an application running that can provide the secret. For example, nm-applet, gnome-shell, plasma-nm (KDE), nmtui, `nmcli --ask` are such applications. If no secret agent program is running, then NetworkManager daemon has nobody to ask.

> Even if I find a way to fix this, how do I prevent users simply choosing one of the 'store the password...' options?

By taking away the policy kit permissions to those users to modify the profile. See `nmcli general permissions` for the permissions you have. The permissions `org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.own` and `org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.system` are relevant here. Read up on PolicyKit.